# Sugar ORM ANDROID

Tags: java, android, orm

Bom dia

Existe alguma maneira de alterar tabelas e campos no banco de dados Sugar ORM, para que ao realizar a atualização do app, ele não trave?

Eu tenho um cadastro e possuo a tabela PRODUTOS e ela contem nome, codigo, local, etc...
Se eu tentar aumentar um campo na tabela, e colocar preço. Quando atualizo o aplicativo o antigo banco não atualiza e chega a se corromper.
O mesmo acontece se eu tentar colocar outra tabela no banco, por exemplo a tabela PESSOAS.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Chegou a olhar a [documentação](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html)?
Estou começando a trabalhar com SugarORM, mas me parece que você pode especificar uma query personalizada para ser executada ao fazer a atualização do database.

Lembrando que ao alterar o database é preciso mudar a versão do banco no manifest para que ele seja reconstruído.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, olhei na documentação e acabei achando isso que você falou, não tinha reparado nisso, muito obrigado.